# Visual Studio Report Viewer 2010 with Internet Explorer 9

Tags: reportviewer, internet-explorer-9

My company has a system running in asp.net using the report viewer to display some reports. After upgrading to Internet Explorer 9, the reports are not displayed correctly when using different zoom from 100%. The problem not occurs when the compatibility mode is seted on IE.
 The problem is easy to be reproduced and i upload some screenshots at https://picasaweb.google.com/102746433851783529556/ReportViewerScreenCaps#
 In the test, I used the examples available in http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/reportviewer
 When viewing with zoom in "Page Width", the top of the report is cut.
 When you view with the zoom in "200%", a track is added on top of the blank report. The problem occurs whith the versions 9 and 10 from rv control.
 Is there a hotfix or workaround for this?
 Thank you.